Screen lock suddenly tells incorrect PIN after entering wrong PIN with correct length
My PIN code to unlock my Galaxy S21 FE phone is 7 digits long. However, if I purposely try to enter an incorrect PIN, I get the incorrect PIN message as soon as I enter 7 characters.
I noticed this earlier today. Before today, I could enter an arbitrary incorrect PIN of any length and the phone wouldn't provide an error unless I hit OK after entering the incorrect PIN.
As far as I know, the phone isn't rooted. However, a sudden change to security functionality in this manner sets off alarm bells. It's running Android 14.
Can someone explain this new behavior/functionality?

This is Samsung's "Confirm PIN without tapping OK".

While Android 14 added an "Auto-confirm unlock" feature (reference), Samsung has implemented this since Android 11 (One UI 3) (reference).
The option can only be toggled when setting up the PIN, and cannot be changed afterward. To switch off/on, the user must re-set the PIN. Also, since Android 14 (One UI 6), this option only appears when the PIN is 6 or more digits (reference).
While this option is on, the system will automatically check and confirm after the user inputs a PIN with the same length, whether it is correct (automatically unlocks) or incorrect (automatically tells that the PIN is incorrect).
